# Why i get Proxy error on AWS elastic beanstalk. Vaadin project

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, runtime-error, vaadin, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

First this this things for help:

- [full log is here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nime11/5edca4de50897accb1fee4bbee023671/raw/c53d8bf9dc118ea567b3ac06be3fc795b4ecaef4/log.txt)
- [Link to a site](http://sample-env.qzjxwmkyrr.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/)

Short version:

When i open my project on local host server it works normally i don't get any problems. But when I open on aws i get this proxy error. I all ready tried to increase time out time whit Load Balancer, but it doesn't help.

Errors on httpd/elasticbeanstalk-error_log

```
[Mon Mar 13 12:31:14 2017] [error] [client 92.37.75.229] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: proxy: error reading status line from remote server localhost:8080, referer: my site
[Mon Mar 13 12:31:14 2017] [error] [client 92.37.75.229] proxy: Error reading from remote server returned by /, referer: my site
```

Errors at httpd/error_log

```
] server is within MinSpareThreads of MaxClients, consider raising the MaxClients setting
```

Here is main code for WebServlet:

```
  @WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "MyUIServlet", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = MyUI.class, productionMode = false)
    public static class MyUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }
```

I connect to RDS data base it all ready work on local host

```
  public static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://test.cgiwnuzpgiyc.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com/MuDataBase";
    public static final String USER = "USER";
    public static final String PASSWORD = "Password";
    public static final String DRIVER_CLASS = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
```

Answer (score 0):

OK guys in my case was problem whit wrong setting of database Security Groups. The IP who can access database was just my PC. So when server try to load code it run out of MaxClients.  I know a lot of AWS now so I can help you if you have any similar problem .